# TypeScript: how to have return type be the type of a parameter?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I have something like this:

```
const shiftObjValues = (obj: Object, shift: number): Object => { ... }
```

I have an interface like such:

```
interface Range {
  start: number;
  end: number;
}
```

Now, this is an `Object` and when it is passed into the function I want the return type to be `Range`.

I don’t want to have to continue doing `as Range` when using the function but I want it to maintain flexible in being able to take in any Object.

Edit: I originally wanted this without generics but didn’t understand generics were usable in a different way (as accepted answer shows)

Comment: `const shiftObjValues = (obj: Object, shift: number): Range => { return myVar as Range }`

Comment: I used `Range` as an example. But if they pass in a `Triangle` for example, it would return a `Triangle`

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use generics?

Comment: **off-topic** You should be using `object` and not `Object` [Do's and Don'ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html)

Comment: Libraries like reselect make [heavy usage of generics](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/blob/master/src/index.d.ts). It's that or use assertions all over, which is a much worse solution.

Comment: A possible answer here is to use overloads. It requires enumerating all possible types, but satisfies the question of returning the correct type while not using generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you want to use a generic (aka type argument) to preserve the incoming type. You can use a type constraint to ensure it is an object.

```
const shiftObjValues = <T extends object>(obj: T, shift: number): T => { /* ... */ }
```

Note I used `object` not `Object`, as `Object` is almost anything in JS, including strings and numbers, which I don't think is what you meant.

Also note that you don't have to explicitly pass the type argument, meaning this works fine:

```
let range: Range = { start: 0, end: 1 };
let shifted = shiftObjValues(range, 1);
// `shifted` is inferred as type `Range`
```

Comment: The question was explicitly about not using a generic. Why I don't know since that should be the answer, but the question excluded it.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I confused myself asto how the generics implementation would go.